# Getting a button to add current user's id to a field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a simple button press that will store current user's id into a field but getting an error that says

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: request):

Here's my code.

The button code

```
<%= form_for(request.accept, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Accept", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

request_controller

```
   def accept
    @request.ssp_id = current_user.id
    @request.save
    flash[:success] = "The request have been accepted!"
  end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.2.2.1

Comment: OK. As a a side note, `form_for` is soft deprecated since Rails 5.1 so you should use `form_with` instead. Also, are you submitting your form through Ajax?

Comment: Nope, not using Ajax yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ParameterMissing` error is probably because you have specified to require `request` model in your parameters through `strong_params`.

Since you are trying to update an existing record with the `current_user` you don't need a form.

Update your accept action in the `RequestsController`:

```
def accept
  @request = Request.find params[:id]
  if @request.update_attribute(:ssp, current_user)
    redirect_to requests_path
    flash[:success] = "The request have been accepted!"
  end
end
```

Request model

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ssp, class_name: "User"
end
```

And your routes:

```
resources :requests do
  member do
    get "accept"
  end
end


<%= link_to 'Accept request', accept_request_path(request) %>
```

Also as a recommendation try to use a different name for your model since the word *request* is wide use in Rails. I don't know if this could be a problem latter on.

Comment: Hmm, not really what I was looking for.  I'm trying to update an existing field in Active Record with current_user id by just pressing a button.  Other fields are working and can be updated.

Comment: Good point about request naming, I'll have to rename it to something else after this.

Comment: OK, let me get this strait. You have a list of `requests`, after the user presses a button, you need to update a field in the `request` with the `current_user.id`. I suppose `current_user` is the one currently logged in. I am correct?

Comment: Thanks, that was it!